# Sylius: Add new Option in Account Management

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I want to add an option to export user data according to the GDPR for each user in my Sylius project.

This should be a new option on the user control panel[image]
There should be a button 'export' next to the save button.

But I am a bit confused how to do this within the sylius system. I have an ExportController, that fetches the user data by the user and sends the generated PDF via mail.

But how can I add overwrite this template and add the button, linking to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, had to check the debug bar in order to find the correct template (Account/profileUpdate.html.twig), copied its content and created a new version of it within the templates folder

Comment: Rule of thumb: always try to avoid overriding entire templates. Instead extend the template and only override specific Twig block from it. Of course it's not always possible.

Comment: @emix true, but i wanted to add id within the form, so this was the easiest way